# Change "a" tag URL using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to change URL in "a" tag inside specific div.

I tried using this code sample but it will change all "a" tag URLs. But I ned to change URL inside class "one" only.

```
<div class="one">
  <a href="http://www.abc.co.uk/"></a>
</div>

<div class="two">
  <a href="http://www.abc.co.uk/"></a>
</div>

$('a[href="http://www.abc.co.uk/"]').attr('href', 'http://www.abc/eye');
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: For reference, see [jQuery Selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), specifically the [class selector](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put `.one` at the beginning of the selector string:

```js
$('.one a[href="http://www.abc.co.uk/"]').attr('href', 'http://www.abc/eye');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="one">
  <a href="http://www.abc.co.uk/">link1</a>
</div>

<div class="two">
  <a href="http://www.abc.co.uk/">link2</a>
</div>
```

There's no need for a big library like jQuery for something this simple:

```js
document.querySelector('.one a[href="http://www.abc.co.uk/"]').href ='http://www.abc/eye';
```

```html
<div class="one">
  <a href="http://www.abc.co.uk/">link1</a>
</div>

<div class="two">
  <a href="http://www.abc.co.uk/">link2</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this without jquery and use some pure JavaScript?

Comment: If div with class "one" has only one a tag, you can as well select it this way: $(".one a").attr("href" , "http://url.com");